# SQL Server Migration for Team Foundation Server 2017

Tags: sql, tfs

we have a TFS 2017 with SQL server 2014. We want to migrate DB from SQL server 2014 to a new SQL 2016 for a future Upgrade to TFS 2018.

I try to following this documentation : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/admin/backup/restore-data-different-instance At the step 7, we are supposed to run this command : TFSConfig PrepSQL but this command is not available in TFS 2017.

Somebody has an idea how to prep the database in TFS 2017 ?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TFSConfig PrepSQL was deprecated. You may find information here: [Deprecated commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/command-line/tfsconfig-cmd#deprecated-commands).

So just skip this step.

Also you may find videos in this post: [Migrating Team Foundation Server 2013 Databases and all Databases in SharePoint 2013 to a New Server](http://mohamedradwan.com/2014/10/22/migrating-team-foundation-server-2013-databases-and-all-databases-in-sharepoint-2013-to-a-new-server/)